# How to share datacontext in nested views using prism?

Tags: wpf, prism

In a project I create the parent view `A`with a `DataContext`; In another project I create a view `B` without `Datacontext`to be injected into view `A`. In this case does `B` inherit the Datacontext of A?

If not, should I create dataContext for each view and use `RegionManager.RegionContext` to share some property between them?

Comment: If it is inserted into view A yes it does inherit DataContext from parent unless it explicitly sets DataContext. It is similar to inserting UserControl, it by default inherits parent's DataContext. When your view B is created it kicks off seeking for local value of DataContext. If no result is found it propagates up to root and because you inserted B in A, root element of A becomes root element for B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does, if your child view is in the logical tree of your parent view. Please read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx).

> This dependency property inherits property values. If there are child
>   elements without other values for DataContext established through
>   local values or styles, then the property system will set the value to
>   be the DataContext value of the nearest parent element with this value
>   assigned.